# How to create a Row from a List or Array in Spark using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to create a Row (`org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Row`) based on the user input. I'm not able to create a Row randomly.

**Is there any functionality to create a Row from `List` or `Array`.**

For eg., If I have a `.csv` file with the following format,

```
"91xxxxxxxxxx,21.31,15,0,0"
```

If the user input `[1, 2]` then I need to take only 2nd column and 3rd column along with the `customer_id` which is the first column

I try to parse it with the code:

```
val l3 = sc.textFile("/SparkTest/abc.csv").map(_.split(" ")).map(r => (foo(input,r(0)))) `
```

where foo is defined as

```
def f(n: List[Int], s: String) : Row = {
    val n = input.length
    var out = new Array[Any](n+1)
    var r = s.split(",")
    out(0) = r(0)
    for (i <- 1 to n)
        out(i) = r(input(i-1)).toDouble
    Row(out)
}
```

and input is a List say

```
val input = List(1,2)
```

Executing this code I get l3 as:

```
Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([[Ljava.lang.Object;@234d2916])
```

But what I want is:

```
Array[org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Row] = Array([9xxxxxxxxxx,21.31,15])`
```

This has to be passed to create a schema in Spark SQL

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._

def f(n: List[Int], s: String) : Row =
  Row.fromSeq(s.split(",").zipWithIndex.collect{case (a,b) if n.contains(b) => a}.toSeq)
```

Comment: This works fine, if I want to parse it as a single row of 3 string values. But how to use it, if the first value is a string, the 2nd and 3rd values are of Double? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing creation of the StructField and StructType. Refer to the official guide http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html, part ***Programmatically Specifying the Schema***

I'm not a Scala specialist, but in Python it would look like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import *
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

input = [1,2]

def parse(line):
    global input
    l = line.split(',')
    res = [l[0]]
    for ind in input:
        res.append(l[ind])
    return res

csv  = sc.textFile("file:///tmp/inputfile.csv")
rows = csv.map(lambda x: parse(x))

fieldnum = len(input) + 1
fields = [StructField("col"+str(i), StringType(), True) for i in range(fieldnum)]
schema = StructType(fields)

csvWithSchema = sqlContext.applySchema(rows, schema)
csvWithSchema.registerTempTable("test")
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM test").collect()
```

In short, you should not directly convert them to Row objects, just leave as RDD and apply schema to it with `applySchema`

Comment: Nice solution - please keep in mind that sqlContext.applySchema is deprecated in spark 2.x, so better use the dataframe-solution.

Comment: What if the data is nested? E.g. we have a `StructType`?

Comment: The question is about how create RDD of Row object, here you create a DataFrame

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
    Row.fromSeq(line(0).toString ++ line(1).toDouble ++ line(2).toDouble ++ line.slice(2, line.size).map(value => value.toString))
```

Comment: Only for scala versions 2.12 up