# trait Row is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code trying to merge two rows:

```
  import org.apache.spark.sql._

  def mergeRow(row1:Row, row2:Row):(Boolean, Row)=  {
      var z:Array[String] = new Array[String](row1.length)
      var hasDiff = false
         :
         :
      if (hasDiff) {
          (true, new Row(z))
      } else {
          (true, row2)
      }
    }
```

And I got the errors:

```
error: trait Row is abstract; cannot be instantiated
             (true, new Row(z))
```

Anyone know how I could fix this ? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28108107/how-to-create-a-row-from-a-list-or-array-in-spark-using-scala might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `new Row(z)` with `Row.fromSeq(z)`

Comment: I'm faced with a similar scenario, but mine is in Java, looks like Java doesn't have Row.fromSeq(z), how can I achieve this please? Thanks!

Comment: RowFactory.create() is the Java way: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html